# Redefine "empty citation" string in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, definition

In biblatex, when no citestring is provided in a cite command, the package prints .
I want to re-define this string.
However, I have not found a documented command or option to do this.

In biblatex.sty this string is defined in line 11413:

```
\def\abx@warn@emptycite@print@text{%
  \textless empty citation\textgreater}
```

How can I redfine this?
I have tried it as follows with no effect:

```
\def\abx@warn@emptycite@print@text{%
  New String}
```

Since I am not familiar with the correct syntax; what would be the correct way to do this?

EDIT: A MWE is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

%% Redefining does not work.
\def\abx@warn@emptycite@print@text{%
  New String}

\begin{document}
    This is an empty citation \cite{}.
\end{document}
``
```

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: If you (re)define commands with an `@` (at) symbol in the name you need to put `\makeatletter` before it and `\makeatother` after, so in this case `\makeatletter \def\abx@warn@emptycite@print@text{New String} \makeatother`. Note that this may not be the full solution, if you provide a short compilable test file then we can try it out.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you! I missed that. This is already the working solution. If you add it as an answer I can mark it as answered :)

Comment: Let's close it as a duplicate of our canonical makeatletter question. Of course the question itself is different but the answer applies, as it states "In practical terms, if you need to modify a package internal macro that contains the @ symbol in its name, you will need to surround your modifications by these commands".